# How to have windows 10 recognize a MSDOS FAT32 formatted USB stick?

Tags: windows-10, usb

I am using a HP EliteBook 840 G8 Notebook running windows 10 Enterprise (with a dock) and I have problems to recognize a USB stick (actually 2 of them). Both are recognized without any issues on a Mac, but not on that windows 10 computer. Both of them! I tried various ports (on computer and dock) but nothing.

Running diskpart and the command `lis dis` I do not see them.
I opened "Computer Management" but I do not see them.

What the hell is going on? Could the USB ports be somehow have been deactivated or maybe there are permission issues?

Comment: How and where were they formatted and on which OS?

Comment: Will the EliteBook recognize _any_ USB drive, as it is possible to prevent Windows from accessing USB drives and is something many corporations do on Enterprise editions since it's good security practice

Comment: Then I guess it is a security practice (as it works without problems when booting the same laptop into ubuntu ...)